Static route problem
I define a local IP address in ubuntu 22.04 and route the real IP address so that the switch does not keep arp records.
I add 2 IPs in ubuntu and define the default gw of the local ip address. I can access from outside but I cannot access from inside to outside, what am I doing wrong?
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
        - 10.250.2.2/30
        - 200.245.48.2/29
      gateway4: 10.250.2.1
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.250.2.1
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
  version: 2


Have you set up netmask? https://superuser.com/questions/1107848/what-is-the-purpose-of-configuring-the-netmask-on-an-ipv4-interface-on-a-linux-m

I can do it in IPv6 but not in IPv4, what do you mean by netmask setup?
https://jsfiddle.net/mzru1dLn/

Sorry about confusion the actual question is does yort ip have a correct netmask? may be you should search to understand what a netmask is, here is one https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/What_is_a_Netmask%3F
